# Docusign API Get Limits in sandbox

Tags: docusignapi, limits

Does DocuSign enforce its limits on Get requests per EnvelopeID in the sandbox?

I have reviewed their publications regarding the 1 Get request per EnvelopeID every 15 minutes and 1000 API requests per hour, however in the sandbox, it appears that I am able to get a valid response when intentionally violating these limits for testing when using the same EnvelopeID and endpoint.  Are these restrictions enforced only in the production environment? I posed the question to Docusign, but they didn't answer and referred me here.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Demo environment limit is more than 1000, for my Sandbox account I can see the limit is 100000. You can always check the Header in the any API call response, it will have below values:

```
X-RateLimit-Limit →100000
X-RateLimit-Remaining →99998
X-RateLimit-Reset →1512680400
```

- `X-RateLimit-Limit` tells your API call limit
- `X-RateLimit-Remaining` tells how many are remaining in this hour
- `X-RateLimit-Reset` tells the time when rate limit counter will be
  rest

Comment: Thanks for your response and insight.